# Object loaded from JSON file returns different result then declared object in JS file

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I'm trying to load an immutable object from json file. After requiring it and inputing it into fromJS function I'm getting the simple JS object back and not Immutable MAP.

I noticed that when I'm creating the object in the same file without requiring it, it works fine.

Also, I noticed when using console log the object that does not get required outputs:

jsonObj.json

```
{
    "im":"a json Object"
}
```

jsObj.js

```
export default {
    "im":"a js object"
}
```

test.js

import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

```
describe('immutable test', ()=>{
    it('should be able to load and parsed json from file',()=>{
        var json = require('./jsonObj.json');
        var js = require('./jsObj.js');
        console.log(json);//output: { im: 'a json Object' }
        console.log(js.default);//outputs: { im: 'a js object' }

        console.log(fromJS(json));//outputs: { im: 'a json Object' } 
        console.log(fromJS(js.default));//outputs: Map { "im": "a js object" }

      //if adding:
        JSON.parse(json);//throws: 
        // SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
        // at Object.parse (native)

    });
});
```

I'm using:

immutable 3.8.1

node  6.3.1

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the actual code? Seems like it's defaulting to a javascript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) rather than the Immutable Map.

Comment: Please add your code. Also, what does "I'm trying to load an immutable object from json file" mean? Are you trying to load JSON and then turn it into an Immutable Map/List? Or do you literally have a serialized version of an Immutable object on disk?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well. I copied your code and got:

```
{ im: 'a json' }
{ im: 'a js object' }
Map { "im": "a json" }
Map { "im": "a js object" }
```

Once you require the `.json` file, it is parsed and stored as a `Javascript object` while `JSON.parse` expects a string, no surprises this throws an error:

```
JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: could be decoding issue?

Comment: which node version are you using? json imports works from v0.5.x, otherwise you'll be importing a string